# TLS1.0 issues in .Net3.5 vs .Net4.0. Windows Server 2008

Tags: ssl, .net-4.0, .net-3.5, windows-server-2008-r2, fiddler

I am working on a Windows Server 2008 box. I have a console app that I'm using to test the handshake between myself and another server. When I build this app under .net4.0 the connection is fine, but when I build the same app under 3.5 the connection will timeout.

One thing I found out is when I use fiddler on the 3.5 app, when I have fiddler "DECRYPT HTTPS TRAFFIC" the handshake goes through just fine, but if this box is not checked it will timeout as usual.

I have a feeling it has something to do with the ciphers and the way .net 3.5 uses them vs .net 4.0.

Has anybody ran into this issue before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing a NetMon or Wireshark (pcap) trace will help resolve this.

With HTTPS decryption disabled in Fiddler, compare the text of the Request TextView inspector for the `CONNECT` tunnels from the working and non-working application. Are different ciphers offered?

It's possible that you're hitting something like this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2012/03/29/https-request-hangs-.net-application-connection-on-tls-server-name-indicator-warning.aspx

Comment: Thank you Eric. That is the exact same issue I was seeing. I ended up finding a couple of blogs and it seems this issue was fixed in .NET 4.0, but earlier versions the only work around is setting ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

Comment: @brian.a.lai: Cool! Can you share some of the blogs you found? Thanks!